# How to cache images which are diplayed with ajax

Tags: html, ajax, json, dom

I'm creating chat. This chat is refreshing every 2 seconds but in messages cold be images.

They reloading every 2 seconds. How to cache images or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be concerned about caching. Almost all modern browsers automatically cache the resources. If you inspect the images you can see that the status will be

> Not Modified 304

Explanation here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html ( at bottom )

That being said, if your application is enterprise level this becomes a different ball game altogether. With huge traffic you should resort to techniques like

1. Content Delivery Networks
2. HTML Compression

Comment: i understand. then you set it as src to the img tag. then only browser goes for the image fetch and it will find the image in its cache and deliver it with a 304 status. and this is just layman terms :)

Comment: I don't understand you. I have div in which i put messages from server in json format. This div is refreshing every 2 seconds. I messages which I put in this div cold be some images. Every 2 seconds every image in this div reloads. What I need to do if I want only one loading for every image?

Comment: @Mirgorod: Just take the site in Firefox, open firebug and check the net tab. you will see a 304 raised and that means the image will be cached already